# How to hide and show labels inside repeater on the basis of data stored in table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two labels (label4 and label5) where the text is retrieved from data stored in column b and column c of a table (tblp). The labels are present inside the repeater control, and now on the basis of data stored in column d of same table, I am trying to show and hide the text of label4 and label5 on page load with the following rules:

- If the column d consists letter s then both label text should be visible.
- If the column d consists letter h then both label text should be invisible.
- If the column d consists letter u then both label text should be visible.

The problem is that when trying to use the label as an argument for the method I have made, the label shows error.

Code samples of what I have done are given below.

HTML

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("b") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("c") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = j.getentry(Label4.Text, Label5.Text);
    if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[0]["d"].ToString() == "s")
        {
            DataTable dp = j.getall();
            if (dp.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = dt;  /*To show text*/
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }

        }
        else if (dt.Rows[0]["d"].ToString() == "h")
        {
            Label4.Visible = false;
            Label5.Visible = false;  /*To hide text*/
        }
        else if (dt.Rows[0]["d"].ToString() == "u")
        {
            DataTable dp = j.getall();
            if (dp.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = dt; /*To show text*/
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Method used

```
 public DataTable getentry(string b, string c)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select *from tblp where b=@b  and c=@c ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
public DataTable getall()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select a,b,c from tblp";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dp = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dp);
    return dp;

}
```

Comment: Did you try to cast "string" the text of the labels before?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is

1.Put a `HiddenField` inside repeater and use `Repeater_ItemDataBound` like this

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidd1" Value='<%#Eval("d") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("b") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("c") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

2. use `Repeater1_ItemDataBound` to iterate through each Repeater Item and by checking condition set the visibility to true or false

**Update** : since you are stroing column D values to Hidden field there is no need to compare your values like this `(dt.Rows[0]["d"].ToString() == "h")`

You can directly compare values stored in hiddenfield on each item binding

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            string hidd1 = ((HiddenField)(e.Item.FindControl("hidd1"))).Value; // find hidden field
            Label l1 = (Label)(e.Item.FindControl("Label4"));// find lable4 value
            Label l2 = (Label)(e.Item.FindControl("Label4"));//// find lable5 value
            if (hidd1.ToLower == "s")// your conditon
            {
                l1.Visible = true;// your code1
                l2.Visible = true;
            }
           else if (hidd1.ToLower == "h")
            {
                l1.Visible = false;// your code2
                l2.Visible = false;
            }
           else
            {
                // defalut
            }
        }
```

if you still have some doubt read more about  [Repeater.ItemDataBound Event here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: :Here i am trying to show text on page load.And as suggested by you to use my condition i.e like dt.Rows[0]["d"].ToString() == "s" in if condition it needs method to be called. So i am totally confused how to do tha that and solve this problem.Till now not solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Visible` attribute

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SomeCondition")) %>' Text='<%#Eval("b") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SomeCondition")) %>' Text='<%#Eval("c") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
else if (dt.Rows[0]["d"].ToString() == "h")
    {
        (Label)(Repeater1.FindControl("Label4")).Visible = false;
       (Label)(Repeater1.FindControl("Label5")).Visible = false;  /*To hide text*/
    }
```